# How do I respond to successful login with Dropbox API on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

It checks whether the user is logged into dropbox when my app is launched. If they are, it continues with code relating to dropbox. If not, it shows them a login screen using `[[DBSession sharedSession] link];`.

From the login screen comes this delegate, if authorization fails:

```
-(void)sessionDidReceiveAuthorizationFailure:(DBSession *)session userId:(NSString *)userId {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] link];
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be something for when authorization succeeds. How do I deal with this scenario? I need to start running the necessary code once they're linked with dropbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You handle successful login from the Dropbox API in the

`-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` function

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {


    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        //Successfully Logged in to Dropbox
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As part of applicationDidFinishLaunching you could initiate the dropbox api you could do the following.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    DBSession* dbSession = [[[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:@"appKey" appSecret:@"appSecret" root:kDBRootAppFolder] autorelease];
    dbSession.delegate = self;  
    [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSharedSessionAvailability  object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:dbSession != nil ? YES : NO]];  
});
```

But normally you simply get your session and use it later via the restClient.